# sibling combinator with styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Trying to build the effect of several cards stacking on each other with styled components.

```
const Card = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: brown;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: solid black;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px 2px rgba(black, 0.75);
  transition: 0.2s;
  &:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -4rem;
  }
  &:hover {
    transform: translateY(-1rem);
  }

  &:hover {
    ~ & {
      transform: translateX(4rem);
    }
  }
`;
```

I want the effect when one card hovers, all cards behind it are pushed away from it. Everything works fine except

```
  &:hover {
    ~ & {
      transform: translateX(4rem);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you add a `class` to the `Card` on `hover` ?

Comment: what does that mean?